# When making the staging site go live, can you simply change the folder names in FTP?

Tags: server, development

I have a staging site called: stg.website.com

I want to make this version of the site my live version now.

In FTP, I have 2 folders

1) stg.website.com (the staging website)

2) www.website.com (the real website)

Why can't I just rename the 2 folders to make the staging site go live? That is, rename stg.website.com to www.website.com?

Comment: That sounds plausible.  It may depend on the operating system and web server.  I don't think there is a lot of harm in trying it.  You can always rename things back if it doesn't work.

Comment: It may be a good idea to keep your staging folder and simply copy the contents to www.  This way, you can continue to try things in your staging environment, without impacting your production environment.